# Passwordless ssh reverse tunnel suddenly asks for password?

Tags: authentication, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, reverse-tunnel

This has me puzzled to no end, hopefully someone can clarify.

I have a local server, LOCALSRV, and remote server (Ubuntu 20.04), REMOTESRV.

On the local server, I've established a reverse ssh tunnel, forwarding LOCALSRV port 5555 to REMOTESRV port 7777, by running `autossh` at boot, using a *passwordless* key authentication:

```
/opt/sbin/autossh -M 51501 -f \
my_tnl_user@REMOTESRV \
-p 51500 -NT -i /path/to/mykey_id_rsa \
-o "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes" \
-o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" \
-R 7777:127.0.0.1:5555
```

When I started this last night, everything worked fine; so `sudo journalctl -t sshd` on REMOTESRV from that time (around 18 o'clock) reports:

```
Nov 18 18:09:51 REMOTESRV sshd[29058]: Disconnected from user my_tnl_user LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 48109
Nov 18 18:09:51 REMOTESRV sshd[28990]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_tnl_user

Nov 18 18:17:49 REMOTESRV sshd[29127]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 50641 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 18:17:49 REMOTESRV sshd[29127]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)
```

Good enough; so now I check everything this morning, and nothing works. The `autossh` log on the LOCALSRV was not too informative (I had forgotten to use `AUTOSSH_DEBUG=1`):

```
...
2021/11/18 18:17:49 autossh[13408]: starting ssh (count 1)
2021/11/18 18:17:49 autossh[13408]: ssh child pid is 13409
2021/11/18 22:58:06 autossh[13408]: timeout polling to accept read connection
2021/11/18 22:58:06 autossh[13408]: port down, restarting ssh
2021/11/18 22:58:06 autossh[13408]: starting ssh (count 2)
2021/11/18 22:58:06 autossh[13408]: ssh child pid is 17556
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: starting ssh (count 3)
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: ssh child pid is 17557
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh

# this then repeats all the way to end, with differing PIDs:

2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: starting ssh (count 4)
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: ssh child pid is 17559
2021/11/18 22:58:07 autossh[13408]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
...
```

So, I cannot tell, what might have happened at 22:58 o'clock, to have caused "timeout polling to accept read connection" and "port down, restarting ssh" (which are the only occurences of those strings in that log).

Thus, I looked into `sudo journalctl -t sshd` on REMOTESRV (linebreak added for legibility):

```
...
Nov 18 18:17:49 REMOTESRV sshd[29127]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 50641 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 18:17:49 REMOTESRV sshd[29127]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)

Nov 18 22:58:06 REMOTESRV sshd[29920]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57231 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 22:58:06 REMOTESRV sshd[29920]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30003]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:51501: Address already in use
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30003]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 51501
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30003]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:7777: Address already in use
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30003]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 7777
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[29920]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_tnl_user
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30004]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57232 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30004]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)
...
```

Right, so here we can see "bind: Address already in use" and "error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port" - and I cannot tell why this happened; closest I found is this:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/903866/multiple-port-forwarding-gives-bind-address-already-in-use
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1014401/ssh-reverse-port-forward-disconnects-each-10-minutes

> In my case, this behavior was caused by simultaneous connections to the server of two computers with the same autossh monitoring port (-M).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757129/reverse-ssh-tunnel-fails-to-bind-to-port-when-tunnel-is-torn-down-and-restarted

> If the client reconnect before the connection has terminated on the server, you can end up in a situation where the new ssh connection is live, but has no port forwardings. In order to avoid that, you need to use the `ExitOnForwardFailure` keyword on the client side.

Eh, but I already use that, don't I?

Now, here's the tricky part - right after the above log `sudo journalctl -t sshd` snippet on REMOTESRV, this repeats for a while:

```
...
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30004]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_tnl_user
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30066]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57233 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 22:58:07 REMOTESRV sshd[30066]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)
Nov 18 22:58:08 REMOTESRV sshd[30127]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:51501: Address already in use
Nov 18 22:58:08 REMOTESRV sshd[30127]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 51501
Nov 18 22:58:08 REMOTESRV sshd[30127]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:7777: Address already in use
Nov 18 22:58:08 REMOTESRV sshd[30127]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 7777
...
```

... and then, it ends like this (spaces added for legibility):

```
...
Nov 18 22:59:11 REMOTESRV sshd[30500]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_tnl_user
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30562]: Accepted publickey for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57263 ssh2: R>
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30562]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_tnl_user by (uid=0)
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30623]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:51501: Address already in use
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30623]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 51501
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30623]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:7777: Address already in use
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30623]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 7777
Nov 18 23:00:01 REMOTESRV sshd[30562]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_tnl_user

Nov 18 23:01:13 REMOTESRV sshd[30624]: Failed password for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57286 ssh2
Nov 18 23:01:13 REMOTESRV sshd[30624]: Failed password for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57286 ssh2
Nov 18 23:01:13 REMOTESRV sshd[30624]: Connection closed by authenticating user my_tnl_user LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port >

Nov 18 23:02:51 REMOTESRV sshd[30627]: Failed password for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57294 ssh2
Nov 18 23:02:51 REMOTESRV sshd[30627]: Failed password for my_tnl_user from LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port 57294 ssh2
Nov 18 23:02:52 REMOTESRV sshd[30627]: Connection closed by authenticating user my_tnl_user LOCALSRV_PUB_IP port >
...
```

So, suddenly, REMOTESRV started asking for ssh password for the user my_tnl_user - even if originally it has been set up as *passwordless* key athentication login, which did work fine?!

What the hell is going on?

So here's the thing: I don't really have access to LOCALSRV, however `autossh` still runs there, and attempts to connect to the server.

I did restart REMOTESRV this morning (Nov 19), and `autossh` on LOCALSRV did attempt to connect to it multiple times already - but it fails everytime, because it tries to use the key authentication, and yet REMOTESRV keeps asking for a password, and failing the authentication.

Can someone explain what happened? And is there anything I can do, - and if so, what - on REMOTESRV, so as to have it accept the key authentication from LOCALSRV again, without asking for password - so that I have a working ssh reverse tunnel again?!

Comment: Can you provide the sshd_config of the remote server? It should be in /etc/ssh.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, @AlectoIrenePerez - and sorry for the delay, here is the [sshd_config](https://gist.github.com/sdbbs/adac006590e83e0fbd6ad93d97bad8c7)